# Finitely Generated Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let be $G$ finitely generated; My question is:
Does always exist $H\leq G,H\not=G$ with finite index?
Of course if G is finite it is true. But $G$ is infinite?

Comment: 1) There are finitely presented infinite simple groups, see e.g. [here](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_2000__92__151_0), Theorem 5.5 for an interesting family. 2) It is easy to show that every finite index subgroup contains a finite index normal subgroup. 3) Combine 1. and 2.

Comment: Thanks!I thought that was easier.

Comment: The additive group of rational numbers does not have a finite index subgroup.

Comment: Is it finitely generated?I don't think so.

Comment: @Lima: No, $\mathbb{Q}$ is quasicyclic (every finitely generated subgroup is cyclic), but not cyclic, so it is not finitely generated.

Comment: ah sorry! dropped a hypothesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

I suspect there are easier and more elegant ways to answer this question, but the following argument is one way to see it:

1. There are finitely generated infinite simple groups:

   - In 1951, Higman constructed the first example in *[A Finitely Generated Infinite Simple Group](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s1-26.1.61)*, J. London Math. Soc. (1951) s1-26 (1), 61–64.
   - Very popular are [Thompson's groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_groups).
   - I happen to like the Burger–Mozes family of finitely presented infinite simple torsion-free groups, described in *[Lattices in product of trees](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_2000__92__151_0)*. Publications Mathématiques de l'IHÉS, 92 (2000), p. 151–194 (full disclosure: I wrote my thesis under the direction of M.B.).
   - See P. de la Harpe, *[Topics in Geometric Group Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=cRT01C5ADroC)*, Complement V.26 for further examples and references.
2. If a group $G$ has a finite index subgroup $H$ then $H$ contains a finite index *normal* subgroup of $G$, in particular no infinite simple group can have a non-trivial finite index subgroup.

See also *[Higman's group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman_group)* for an example of a finitely presented group with no non-trivial finite quotients. By the same reasoning as above it can't have a non-trivial finite index subgroup.

Comment: Is point 2. well known? Is it obvious with sufficient thought? (by well-known I mean to students, rather than professionals/experts)

Comment: @benmachine: Yes, I think it's well known in your sense. It's easy to prove: $G$ acts by on the set of cosets $G/H$. Thus you get a homomorphism $G \to \operatorname{Aut}(G/H)$ and you can take its kernel $N \subset H$. Then $G/N$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(G/H)$ and the latter has order dividing $n!$ if $H$ has index $n$.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds reasonable. I'd never heard the result before but I guess it just hasn't come up. Shouldn't $H$ be inside $N$, though, rather than the other way around?

Comment: No, I meant what I wrote. $H$ can very well permute the $G/H$-cosets.

Comment: @t-b: hmm, perhaps we're thinking of different actions: it would possibly help if you weren't missing the verb in the action of $G$ on the cosets :P

Comment: I implement $G/H = \{aH\,:\,a \in G\}$ as left cosets and act with $G$ on the *left* $g(aH) = (ga)H$ (action on the right won't be well-defined!). Just cross out the "by" in my first comment to you or add the *noun* bijections... :) See example 2.9 on p. 4 of Keith Conrad's [blurb](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/gpaction.pdf).

Comment: Oh, we're thinking of the same action and I'm just being silly. Sometimes it helps to be literally staring at the definition! Anyway, thank you for clearing that up.